# highchart feed data from php json

Tags: javascript, php, json, graph, highcharts

I am trying to feed `json` data to highchart but graph appear blank, This is what i need sample: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-rotated-labels/

`values.php` generating `json` output

```
[["10000164@example",4],["10000166@example",2],["10000173@example",1],["10000177@example",3]]
```

Here in the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Highcharts Bar Chart</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var options = {
    chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'World\'s largest cities per 2014'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cities_proper_by_population">Wikipedia</a>'
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
            labels: {
                rotation: -45,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: 'Population in 2008: <b>{point.y:.1f} millions</b>'
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Population',
            data: [],  

            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                rotation: -90,
                color: '#FFFFFF',
                align: 'right',
                x: 4,
                y: 10,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '13px',
                    fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                    textShadow: '0 0 3px black'
                }
            }
        }]
            $.getJSON("values.php", function(json) {
               options.series[0].data = json;
              chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
           });

        });
});  
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="container" style="min-width: 500px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>    
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you build the chart inside the callback function instead of defining all the options first?
Maybe try something like this:

```
$.getJSON('values.php', function (json) {

        $('#container').highcharts({
            series: [{
              data: json
            ]},
            title: {
              text: 'Some Title'
            },
            subtitle: ...
```

I can't demo the ajax request but if you put that json straight in the data option, the charts renders like this: 
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0qc3r0mz/)